# matplotlib grid arrangement for three plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot 3 plots in the following arrangement

```
------------------------ 
| ax1                  | 
------------------------
---------------  ------- 
|   ax2       | | ax3  |
---------------- -------
```

so ax2 should make up about 6/10 of the space and ax3 should use 4/10 of the space.

This was my idea, but it does not work:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(2,10, figsize=(10,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,0), colspan=10)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 0), colspan=6)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 1), colspan=4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but I think you need to multiply everything up to have enough subplots for all rows and columns. Try:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((10,10), (0,0), colspan=10, rowspan=5)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((10,10), (5,0), colspan=6, rowspan=5)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((10,10), (5,6), colspan=4, rowspan=5)
```

Output:

[image]

(You might want to play around a bit with the axis ticks and padding...)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should give what you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1, 2), colspan=1)

plt.show()
```

Im trying to work out why what you wrote didn't work.. brb

Comment: The reason why `plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,0), colspan=10)` doesn't work is that you'd create a subplot on a grid with 2 columns and then instruct it to expand over 10 columns. `colspan` cannot be larger as the number of coluns in the grid.